# Firebird: Access Denied

Tags: firebird

When ever I try to create a database with SQI Tools for firebird I receive this error...

```
SQL> create database 'C:\Remake'
CON> user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "CreateFile (create)" operation for file "C:\REMAKE"
-Error while trying to create file
-Access is denied.
SQL>
```

I went to the `C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0` directory in CMD by using the cd command and then typed isql. I have also tried this when running cmd as the Administrator. I have googled this issue many times and all I get back is responses for Linux to do with the terminal, can anyone help me with Windows?

I am a first time firebird user, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280679/firebird-permission-denied

Comment: IIRC by default you are not allowed - by Windows - to create files into the C:\ drive root. Make sure you create a folder and create the database file there. Also note that it is customary (but not required) to give Firebird databases the extension `.fdb`.

Answer (score 2):

By default you are not allowed - by Windows - to create files into the C:\ drive root, except when running as Administrator. Make sure you create a folder and create the database file there. Also note that it is customary (but not required) to give Firebird databases the extension `.fdb`.

Also make sure that `C:\Remake` does not already exist as a folder (directory), see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280679/firebird-permission-denied